# Different branches in repositories

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-branch

When I see my branches in a local repository with git branch in the terminal it prints only one, which is master
But when I go to the gitlab page I have two branches that are main and master, the main branch by default is main but in master I have all the changes

1 is this normal? that is to say, that in local it has a branch and in remote two

2 how can I just cook them? that is, to have the branches synchronized

3 how can I merge them through gitlab?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `git branch -a`?

Comment: Yes, it prints 

* master (in green)
  remotes/origin/master (in red)

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course, it is possible, that on remote more branches exists then local. Imagine if several developers work in a repository, not every branch is also local by every developer.  Only the needed branches to work are downloaded local.

So at first, do a `git fetch`, to pull all the remote branches to your local repository. With `git branch -a` you can list all branches.

To merge the branches, you can do via command line (to merge `master` in `main` do: `git checkout master` and afterwards `git merge main`) or create in GitLab a [*Merge Request*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/creating_merge_requests.html).

Normally, a repository have only a `main` or a `master` branch, but not both. Widespread are `develop`/`dev` - in addition to `main`/`master` - and `feature-branches` (mostely for smaller tasks). Nobody tells you a branch-policy, unless you want to work as example with [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow#:%7E:text=Gitflow%20is%20a%20legacy%20Git,software%20development%20and%20DevOps%20practices.).